# Failed to connect to sever while pinging with ansible

Tags: linux, shell, ansible, redhat

I am trying to ping to server using ansible

```
ansible -m ping all -vvv
```

My hosts file path is anstest/hosts.txt and Data is

```
[servers]

10.4.74.15 ansible_user=scmuser

server1 ansible_host=10.167.70.15 ansible_ssh_user=muser ansible_ssh_pass=Cdjbfjk

[all:vars]

ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python
```

while pinging i am getting the error Output

```
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method

script declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method

auto declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method

Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin

META: ran handlers

<10.4.74.15> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None


10.4.74.15 | UNREACHABLE! => {

    "changed": false, 

    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh:
```

Tried alot ..cant find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Ansible is not parsing your designated SSH user, as you can see it states:

```
<10.4.74.15> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
```

This should read:

```
<10.4.74.15> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: scmuser
```

Ansible isn't using either of `ansible_user` nor `ansibe_ssh_user` declared in your inventory file.

Go over your inventory file and look for possible errors, as the log entries in your paste imply Ansible is not happy with it.